# X Y Z data to smooth 3D surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I want to make a 3D surface from X,Y,Z (lan,long,depth).

I use 3D scatter and get scatter like this [scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgj6C.png).

So I want to make a 3d surface with interpolation from X and Y position nearby it and the graph will make smooth 3d curve and I am doing like this

[3d surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKqKo.png)

Here is my code

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 import math
 from matplotlib import cm
 from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
 from scipy import interpolate
 from scipy.interpolate import interp2d



 kebenaran = True
 kebenaranz = True
 wb = load_workbook(filename = 'olda.xlsx')
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


 sheet = wb['Sheet1']

 SumbuX = []
 SumbuX2 = []
 SumbuY = []
 SumbuY2 = []
 SumbuZ = []

 i = 3

 while (kebenaran):
     DatX = sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value
     DatY = sheet.cell(row=i, column=12).value
     DatZ = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
     if DatX == None :
         kebenaran = False
     else :
         SumbuX.append(DatX)
         SumbuY.append(DatY)
         SumbuZ.append(DatZ)
         i = i + 1


     x1 = math.floor(min(SumbuX))
     y1 = math.floor(min(SumbuY))
     x2 = math.ceil(max(SumbuX))
     y2 = math.ceil(max(SumbuY))

     X = np.linspace(x1, x2, 3342)
     Y = np.linspace(y1, y2, 3342)


     xm,ym = np.meshgrid(X, Y)


     for i in range(len(SumbuZ)):

        Xdot = math.ceil(SumbuX[i])
        Ydot = math.ceil(SumbuY[i])

        if Xdot < 0 :
            CalcX = Xdot*2*(-1) + Xdot
            if Ydot < 0:
                CalcY = Ydot*2*(-1) + Ydot
            else :
                CalcY = Ydot*2 + Ydot
        else :
            CalcX = Xdot*2 + Xdot
            if Ydot < 0:
                CalcY = Ydot*2*(-1) + Ydot
            else :
                CalcY = Ydot*2 + Ydot
        SumbuX2.append(CalcX)
        SumbuY2.append(CalcY)

    arrX = np.asarray(SumbuX2)
    arrY = np.asarray(SumbuY2)
    arrZ = np.asarray(SumbuZ)

    panjangZ = len(arrZ)


    dot = np.column_stack((arrX,arrY))

    grid_z0 = interpolate.griddata(dot, arrZ, (xm, ym), method='nearest')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, grid_z0)
    plt.show()
```

and here is my data (olda.xlsx)
https://github.com/irfanrah/BathymetryKapal/blob/master/15:24:46.xlsx (olda.xlsx but i haven't rename it)

[oldaimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNd7.png)

Comment: post your data as text. Nobody is going to manually enter all those data points

Comment: There also exists [`tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) to create a 2D contour plot from non-grid data. That could help to get a better idea about what to expect.

Comment: i already add those data points. thank you :)